# set string array from php?

Tags: php

I am a newbie in Php and this might be a quite basic question.

I would like to set string array and put values to array then get values which

I put to string array. so basically,

I want

```
ArrayList arr = new ArrayList<String>;
int limitSize = 20;
    for(i = 0; i < limitSize; i++){
          String data = i + "th";
          arr.add(data);
          System.out.println(arr.get(i));
    };
```

How can I do this in php?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's far less verbose in PHP. Since it isn't strongly typed, you can just append any values onto the array. It can be done with an incremental for loop:

```
$array = array();
$size = 20;
for ($i = 0; $i < $size; $i++) {
  // Append onto array with []
  $array[] = "{$i}th"; 
}
```

...or with a foreach and `range()`

```
foreach (range(0,$size-1) as $i) {
  // Append onto array with []
  $array[] = "{$i}th";     
}
```

It is strongly recommended that you [read the documentation on PHP arrays.](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.array.php)

Comment: `range(0,$size - 1)` to be equivalent to the for loop.

Comment: doesn't "$ith" look for the variable named `$ith` ?

Answer (score 2):

```
$arr = array();
$limitSize = 20;
for($i = 0; $i < $limitSize; $i++){
      $data = $i . "th";
      $arr[] = $data;
      echo $arr[$i] . "\n";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In php arrays are always dynamic. so you can just use `array_push($arrayName,$val)` to add values and use regular for loop processing and do

```
for ($i=0; $i<count($arrName); $i++) {
    echo $arr[$i];
}
```

to print /get value at i.